# Git: autocomplete my prompt after failed push because missing -u flag

Tags: bash, git, autocomplete

Using git, I often create local branches and then want to push them to the remote (e.g. Github). This requires the `-u` or `--set-upstream` flag.

Here is what `git` outputs without this flag:

```
$ git checkout -b newbranch
$ git push
fatal: The current branch cross_val has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin newbranch
```

Is there a way to have this suggestion copied to my prompt? So that I don't have to type it. Something like:

```
$ git checkout -b newbranch
$ git push
fatal: The current branch cross_val has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin newbranch

$ <tab>
$ git push --set-upstream origin newbranch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up an alias that pushes the current branch to the remote.

Configure the alias with the following command:

```
git config --global alias.rpush '!git push --set-upstream origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)'
```

The `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` command returns the name of your current branch. Then run it with:

```
git rpush
```

You can choose to give the alias any other name according to your own preference.

Answer (score 0):

This won't do exactly what you want,  but it will cut down the amount you need to type if you're using bash.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

Comment: I don't think this helps as the git completion scripts are already installed with `git`.

Comment: Guess it depends on the system.  On my linux system it is a separate install and bashrc or profile needs to be updated to take advantage of it.